# Inserting an origin tangential to a sphere

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I am trying to draw a picture like the one attached. I have not used much of the `tikz` package. My code so far is a follows. I what to include a set of angles in the image. Any help would be great and if anyone knows a good pdf or book that goes through the basics of the `tikz` package it would be great.

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt,a4paper]{report}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

%draw of base circles and ellipse's
\draw(0,0,0)   circle   (2.0);
\draw (0,0,0) ellipse (2.0 and 0.3);
\draw (0,0,0) ellipse (0.75 and 2.0);

%drawing of the Earth-Centered-Earth_Fixed (ECEF) Frame
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (2.3,0,0) node[right,anchor=north east,right]{$e_x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2.3,0) node[anchor=north west,above]{$e_z$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0.71,3) node[anchor=south,left]{$e_y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: The TiKZ manual is excellent. `texdoc tikz` or find it on CTAN.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a solution via `tikz-3dplot`. One probably wants to try different view angles in `\tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{95}`, say, (85,90) (85,100) (75,100) to see th 3D effects.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{95}
%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rvec}{.8}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thetavec}{40}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phivec}{35}
%
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.1,0.7,0.1}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$X{\text{ecef}}$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$Y_{\text{ecdf}}$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$Z_{\text{ecef}}$};

\tdplotsetcoord{P}{\rvec}{\thetavec}{\phivec}
\draw[-stealth,color=red] (O) -- (P);
\draw[dashed, color=red, shorten >=-20pt ] (O) -- (Pxy);
\tdplotdrawarc{(O)}{0.4}{0}{\phivec}{anchor=north}{$\lambda$}
\tdplotdrawarc[blue]{(O)}{0.8}{-90}{90}{}{}
\tdplotdrawarc[dashed,blue]{(O)}{0.8}{90}{270}{}{}
%
\tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\phivec}
\tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{0.5}{\thetavec}%
{90}{right}{$\phi$}
\tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{0.8}
{0}{90}{}{}
%
\tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{0}
\tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{0.8}{0}{90}{left}{\rotatebox[origin=cc]{85}{Prime Meridian}}
%
\tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{90}
\tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords,blue]{(0,0,0)}{0.8}
{0}{360}{}{}
%
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\phivec}{\thetavec}{0}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoordsorigin{(P)}
\draw[thick,tdplot_rotated_coords,-,draw=green,fill=white] (-0.1,-0.1,0)
-- (-0.1,0.1,0) -- (0.1,0.1,0)  -- (0.1,-0.1,0)  -- cycle  ;
\draw[thick,tdplot_rotated_coords,->,green] (0,0,0)
-- (-0.5,0,0) node[anchor=west]{$North$};
\draw[thick,tdplot_rotated_coords,->,green] (0,0,0)
-- (0,0.5,0) node[anchor=south]{$East$};
\draw[thick,tdplot_rotated_coords,->,green] (0,0,0)
-- (0,0,0.5) node[anchor=south]{$Up$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks this is almost prefect. I tried to move the frame attached to the circle to the right in free space, but I keep getting errors. If someone could help or give me a link to a web sight that goes through a few examples for the package being used  that would be great.

Comment: @CillianO'Brien -- That is a tricky one. I started out an example from the `tikz3dplot` manual on page 27-28 where the point P (red arrow tip) is the Origin and x'-y'-z' coordinate system is the local coordinate. From there, I figured out how to draw the frame. So if you want to move the frame, I think you need to figure out the x'-y'-z' local system first. Hope this helps.